# Oracle: Query table in tablespace

Tags: oracle

I have a tablespace, ts, that contains table1.

How do I query the contents of table1?

I've tried the following without success:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM table1
WHERE tablespace_name = 'ts';
```

Comment: did you try without the where clause?

Comment: I think you are confusing the data dictionary, which would show which tablespace a table is in (probably as 'TS' not 'ts' - unless you used a quoted identifier), with the table itself. Once the table has been created you won't usually need to know or care about its tablespace - at least until you run out of space *8-)

Comment: I did. It came back saying the table or view couldn't be found.

Comment: Then it doesn't exist in the schema you are currently logged into (or if you've changed your `current_schema`, it doesn't exist, or you don't have privileges to see it, in that schema). Are you perhaps also confusing tablespace and schema - does `select count(*) from ts.table1` also get ORA-00942? Can you see it and its owner if you `select owner, table_name from all_tables where upper(table_name) = 'TABLE1'` and if so is the name returned in lower case?

Comment: Running ```select count(*) from ts.table1``` results in ORA-00942.
Running ```select owner, table_name from all_tables where upper(table_name) = 'TABLE1'``` returns the owner of the table and it is returned in upper case.
The owner name and the schema name are the same.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more context is required. I'm coming from a SQL Server background. Oracle 19c is installed on a host. 2 tablespaces were created for our application. The application created 3 users, admin, user and read_only and created the required tables etc in the 2 created tablespaces. The issue I'm going to run into is that more than 1 instance of the application is going to connect to Oracle 19c and I need to be able to query the tables on each tablespace for each instance of our application. Right now, I fear all instances of our application will write to the same tables.

Answer (score 0):

> 2 tablespaces were created for our application. The application created 3 users, admin, user and read_only and created the required tables etc in the 2 created tablespaces. The issue I'm going to run into is that more than 1 instance of the application is going to connect to Oracle 19c and I need to be able to query the tables on each tablespace for each instance of our application.

Each of the three users can have tables in either or both tablespaces. Once a table has been created it usually doesn't matter much which tablespace it is in - that is an administration issue, not something users generally need to be aware of.

All of the users can all have tables with the same names. That's fine. Each table will belong to a user (schema), and the names have to be unique within that schema, but not globally.

> I fear all instances of our application will write to the same tables.

There are a couple of basic approaches.

1. Each instance of the application can connect as a different user and look only at that user's tables. If the connection is made as `admin` then `select * from table` would return data from admin's version of the table.
2. Each instance could connect as the same user, which owns no tables itself, and then specify which other user's (schema's) tables it wants to access. It can do that by querying say `select * from admin.table1`, or as part of the connection set-up do `alter session set current_schema = admin` and then just `select * from table1` will look as admin's table by default.